# Alterar o tamanho de um gráfico com JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho o seguinte gráfico:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      spanProcent = document.getElementById('procent'),
       c = can.getContext('2d');
 
  var posX = can.width / 2,
      posY = can.height / 2,
      fps = 1000 / 200,
      procent = 0,
      oneProcent = 360 / 100,
      result = oneProcent * 64;
  
  c.lineCap = 'round';
  arcMove();
  
  function arcMove(){
    var deegres = 0;
    var acrInterval = setInterval (function() {
      deegres += 1;
      c.clearRect( 0, 0, can.width, can.height );
      procent = deegres / oneProcent;

      spanProcent.innerHTML = procent.toFixed();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + 360) );
      c.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
      c.lineWidth = '6';
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + deegres) );
      c.stroke();
      if( deegres >= result ) clearInterval(acrInterval);
    }, fps);
    
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
:root {
  background: #fff;
}

span#procent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #3949AB;
}

span#procent::after {
  content: '%';
}

.canvas-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <span id="procent"></span>
</div>
```

Ao tentar diminuir o tamanho do width e heigth para 100px, por exemplo, apenas as pontas dentro do quadrado aparecem, como faço para diminuir a circunferência desse gráfico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você diminuiu `1/3` (um terço) do tamanho do canvas. Deve ajustar as propriedades proporcionalmente. Por exemplo, a posição do gráfico foi reduzido em `200px`, logo deve reposicionar pela metade da diferença original, usando `top` e `left` em `100px`:

```
#canvas{
   position: relative;
   left: 100px;
   top: 100px;
}
```

Deve também reduzir o tamanho do `.arc`. Reduzi de `70` para `45`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      spanProcent = document.getElementById('procent'),
       c = can.getContext('2d');
 
  var posX = can.width / 2,
      posY = can.height / 2,
      fps = 1000 / 200,
      procent = 0,
      oneProcent = 360 / 100,
      result = oneProcent * 64;
  
  c.lineCap = 'round';
  arcMove();
  
  function arcMove(){
    var deegres = 0;
    var acrInterval = setInterval (function() {
      deegres += 1;
      c.clearRect( 0, 0, can.width, can.height );
      procent = deegres / oneProcent;

      spanProcent.innerHTML = procent.toFixed();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc( posX, posY, 45, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + 360) );
      c.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
      c.lineWidth = '6';
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.arc( posX, posY, 45, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + deegres) );
      c.stroke();
      if( deegres >= result ) clearInterval(acrInterval);
    }, fps);
    
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
:root {
  background: #fff;
}

span#procent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #3949AB;
}

span#procent::after {
  content: '%';
}

.canvas-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#canvas{
   position: relative;
   left: 100px;
   top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
  <span id="procent"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra opção rápida caso queira diminuir o gráfico como um todo, largura das linhas etc *(menos o texto!)* basta usar um `transform:scale()` no `canvas`.

O `scale()` funciona assim, o valor original é `(1)`, se vc quiser que ele dobre de tamanho vc coloca `(2)`, e se quiser a metade do tamanho `(0.5)`. Vc pode perceber que cada `0.1` representa `10%` do tamanho original.

Veja o exemplo utilizando o `transforme:scale()` e **repare que diferente da resposta do Sam aqui todos os elementos dentro do `canvas` são diminuídos proporcionalmente.** 
**OBS:** Se quiser aplicar no texto também ai vc pode incluir o `transforme` tb no `ID` `procent`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      spanProcent = document.getElementById('procent'),
       c = can.getContext('2d');

  var posX = can.width / 2,
      posY = can.height / 2,
      fps = 1000 / 200,
      procent = 0,
      oneProcent = 360 / 100,
      result = oneProcent * 64;

  c.lineCap = 'round';
  arcMove();

  function arcMove(){
    var deegres = 0;
    var acrInterval = setInterval (function() {
      deegres += 1;
      c.clearRect( 0, 0, can.width, can.height );
      procent = deegres / oneProcent;

      spanProcent.innerHTML = procent.toFixed();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + 360) );
      c.strokeStyle = '#b1b1b1';
      c.lineWidth = '6';
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.strokeStyle = '#3949AB';
      c.lineWidth = '10';
      c.arc( posX, posY, 70, (Math.PI/180) * 270, (Math.PI/180) * (270 + deegres) );
      c.stroke();
      if( deegres >= result ) clearInterval(acrInterval);
    }, fps);

  }

}
```

```css
:root {
  background: #fff;
}

span#procent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #3949AB;
}

span#procent::after {
  content: '%';
}

.canvas-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#canvas {
  transform: scale(.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <span id="procent"></span>
</div>
```